# Error: forming pointer to reference type 'const std::pair<double, unsigned int>&'.... I can't understand this error

Tags: pointers, boost, c++11

I'm getting some errors when trying to use -> in an iterator type. When I dig in the library defining the iterator, it seems to me that everyhing is allright and that there is no reason for the error. Here is the code, part of boost::multi_array:

```
template <class T>
struct operator_arrow_proxy
{
  operator_arrow_proxy(T const& px) : value_(px) {}
  T* operator->() const { return &value_; }
  // This function is needed for MWCW and BCC, which won't call operator->
  // again automatically per 13.3.1.2 para 8
  operator T*() const { return &value_; }
  mutable T value_;
};
```

which is instantiated with `const std::pair<double, unsigned int>&`; then the compiler complains about "*forming pointer to reference type 'const std::pair<double, unsigned int>&'*".Those are internal, library substantiations. For the record, here is what I have in *my* code:

```
typedef uint32_t object_indentifier_t;
typedef std::pair< double, object_identifier_t > object_tab_t;
typedef boost::multi_array< object_tab_t, 2 > index_t;
```

and here is the usage that provokes the trouble:

```
object_identifier const& center; // Actually a parameter
index_t::const_subarray<1>::type::const_iterator pos_iterator_left = std::lower_bound( ix[i].begin(), ix[i].end(), sk[i], comparer ); 
assert( pos_iterator_left -> second == center ); // <-- Error steams from here
```

Here's more error context:

```
/opt/boost_1_48_0/include/boost/multi_array/iterator.hpp: In instantiation of 'struct boost::detail::multi_array::operator_arrow_proxy<const std::pair<double, unsigned int>&>':
csrc/lsh_cpp/lsh.cpp|125 col 13| required from here
/opt/boost_1_48_0/include/boost/multi_array/iterator.hpp|40 col 10| error: forming pointer to reference type 'const std::pair<double, unsigned int>&'
/opt/boost_1_48_0/include/boost/multi_array/iterator.hpp|43 col 7| error: forming pointer to reference type 'const std::pair<double, unsigned int>&'
 csrc/lsh_cpp/lsh.cpp: In member function 'lsh_cpp::neighbour_iterator_t lsh_cpp::lsh_t::pimpl_t::query(const object_identifier_t&) const':
csrc/lsh_cpp/lsh.cpp|125 col 13| error: result of 'operator->()' yields non-pointer result
```

NOTE: This class is part of boost::multi_array, (I already wrote that), and I'm not instantiating it directly. I wrote above my instantiation. The class is instantiated by boost::multi_array this way:

```
 operator_arrow_proxy<reference>
 operator->() const
 {
     return operator_arrow_proxy<reference>(this->dereference());
 }
```

The use of "reference" makes me think that the reference is intended. Is there a reason for taking address to a reference to not work? I think to remember having done it myself a couple of times, and getting the address of the original, aliased variable that way....

Comment: When you are getting some errors, you have to quote them. Exactly and including all the "notes" around that show the stack of template instantiations being expanded and parameters used.

Comment: Apparently `operator_arrow_proxy` gets instantiated with reference type as argument, which it clearly shouldn't. But it's not clear how the reference got there if you don't include the complete diagnostic provided by the compiler.

Comment: I included the full error message. As a note, this time gcc is not giving the full instantiation chain. I traced it manually though, and using a reference to instantiate this struct is *intended*. Can you say why taking a pointer to this reference would be a problem? I think that this syntax would return the address of the original variable....

Comment: It would be nicer if the error message was not passed through vim.

Comment: @JanHudec why would that make a difference?

Comment: @dsign Please make it a http://sscce.org/ **there you go: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f5093afa98761152**

Comment: @sehe: Well, I don't completely trust vim not to be hiding the extra lines that don't have the usual file:line:what format.

Comment: @JanHudec okay. I do, but you have a point

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taking address of a reference is not a problem, but it returns pointer to the underlying type, not pointer to reference. Pointers to reference can't be created nor would they make sense since references cannot be rebound. Declaring a pointer to reference type is an error.

The return type `T *` therefore won't work if `T` is a reference type. Similarly declaring a `mutable T` makes no sense if `T` is a reference type, because references cannot be rebound. So the `operator_arrow_proxy` is apparently written to expect a non-reference.

If boost instantiates it with `reference` member of anything, which is *always* a reference type, it looks like a bug. Indeed, appears to be reported as [bug #6554](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/6554).

Comment: Yes, it is a bug: https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/6554. Not fixed yet in trunk, although the patch is there and the fix is trivial...