# initializer_lists of streams (C++11)

Tags: c++11, ofstream, initializer-list

I'm trying to pass variable number of ofstreams over to a function that accepts an initializer_list but doesn't seem to work and throws all possible errors from the initializer_list structure and about how my function is with an array of ofstreams cannot be matched to any defined function.

Is it actually possible to pass a reference of ofstreams over in an initializer_list?

*test.cpp*

```
#include "extension.h"


ofstream outputFile, outputFile2;

int main(void) {

    outputFile.open(("data_1.txt");
    outputFile2.open("data_2.txt");
    writeSomething({outputFile, outputFile2});
    outputFile.close();
    outputFile2.close();
}
```

*extension.h*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <initializer_list>

using namespace std;

void writeSomething(initializer_list<ofstream&> args);
```

*extension.cpp*

```
#include "extension.h"

void writeSomething(initializer_list<ofstream&> args) {
    for (auto f : args ) {
        f << "hello" << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: fstreams are not copyable, and initializer_lists only allow you to copy their contents. So whether it works or not depends on how you're populating the initializer_list and what the function does with it. IOW, please post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**clang 3.4 (trunk 194324) produces a pretty clear error message:**

> initializer_list:54:23: error: 'iterator' declared as a pointer to a
>   reference of type
>         `'std::basic_ofstream<char> &'`
>         `typedef const _E*         iterator;`

**So no, it is not possible.** See also [Error: forming pointer to reference type 'const std::pair&'… I can't understand this error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19397737/341970).

(gcc 4.7.2 and 4.8.1 crashes on this code due to some internal compiler error. I have submitted a [bugreport](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=59550).)

What you could do instead is to pass a pointer instead of a reference, something like this:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <initializer_list>

using namespace std;

void writeSomething(initializer_list<ofstream*> args) {
    for (auto f : args )
        *f << "hello" << endl;
}

int main() {
    ofstream outputFile("data_1.txt");
    ofstream outputFile2("data_2.txt");
    writeSomething({&outputFile, &outputFile2});
}
```

**However, I would much rather use a `std::vector` instead.** Using an initializer list for this purpose is very strange and confusing for me.